# apache www.domain.com not working but domain.com does

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web

Im using ubuntu 13, and apache2
inside the **/etc/apache2/sites-available**  I created a domain.com file with the virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin my@email.com
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

I've enabled the virtual host file : sudo a2ensite domain.com
I've restarted apache after this

but I still cant access www.domain.com and domain.com works fine

any clues are super appreciated!

Comment: Does `www.domain.com` properly resolve to the correct IP address through DNS? If not, then no amount of Apache tweaking will allow external systems to access it by that name...

Comment: @Filipe Zuleta, have you solved this, and if so how? I have the same issue. Please send me the link if you found some quality resource. Thx

Comment: Hi @NemanjaMilosavljevic , sorry for the very late reply, yeah, I had to add a DNS CNAME :  www  with a value of domain.com.

Comment: @Filipe Zuleta me 2. Thanks :)